# generate chm from doxygen results

Tags: html, doxygen, chm

For some reasons, I would not be long, I can't bring my source code to Windows.
I want to generate doxygen and get CHM file too.
so I generated doxygen  on Linux, now I what to know can I copy the html files to linux and generate the chm file , I rather using doxygen, but couldn't figure out how to do it only from the html files and not on the source code.
Any ideas?

Comment: I maintain a *nix CHM compiler called "chmcmd" which is part of the "freepascal" distribution. I know that people use it with doxygen, just not how :-)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have the source code on Linux and no way to copy to Windows. Please try to generate the HTML files by Doxygen on Linux with the properties shown on the attached snap. The files you need later are marked. Make shure you get these files.

1. Prepare a Windows machine
2. Install HTMLHelp Workshop
   http://www.help-info.de/en/Help_Info_HTMLHelp/hh_download_install.htm
3. Copy all files including index.hhp, index.hhk and index.hhp from LINUX to Windows
4. Right click to index.hhp
5. Open with HTMLHelp Workshop or e.g a tool like 'FAR HTML'
6. Compile with HTMLHelp Workshop (note there is a icon on the toolbar)
7. Copy the resulting CHM back to Linux and view by e.g.
   http://www.linux.com/news/software/applications/8209-chm-viewers-for-linux

Or learn CHMcmd as mentioned by Marco van de Voort above.

[image]