# howto convert a Doxygen HTML documentation to .chm file

Tags: doxygen, chm

I have a nearly ready Doxygen documentation, with dependence graphs, TOC, etc.
How can I convert it to .chm?
(Under Ubuntu 16.04 I installed HTML Help Workshop in a VirtualBox, and I think I can make .hhp (I do not have graphs, only placekeepers, no TOC, etc.)
Shall I configure something extra? How .hhk and .hhc shall be generated?

Comment: Please try to generate the HTML files by Doxygen on Linux with the properties shown by the snap in my answer at [Generate chm from doxgen results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23680921/generate-chm-from-doxgen-results/24468819#24468819)

Comment: I assume that with VirtualBox you mean a virtual machine running Windows. In the Doxyfile you can (a.o.) set GENERATE_HTMLHELP to generate necessary files and HHC_LOCATION to specify where to find hcc help compiler )See documentation chapter about configuration or directly in the Doxyfile).

Comment: @albert I am generating the HTML files under Linux, and .chm under Windows XP

Comment: I think you can create the required files all under Linux (setting GENERATE_HTMLHELP etc.) the generation of the final chm file will fail but this is not a problem. After this transfer the files the the XP box (probably you have to use the command unix2dos on the hhk etc files). Now run the hhc on the files. When using doxygen on Linux use the option -d extcmd so you can see what doxygen tried to start for the hhc part and gives you the information about how to run it on windows.

Comment: As mentioned above try to compile with the steps on your Windows XP machine. Please try to compile from the *.hhp File.